# Send Multiple request.getRequestDispatcher()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my servlet, I pass the attribute to my jsp page:

```
request.setAttribute("value", value);
request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

but I also want to pass the attribute to the mobile-friendly jsp page. I tried placing this line underneath the above code to no avail. Can I pass an attribute to multiple jsp pages?

`request.getRequestDispatcher("m_home.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to forward to both a desktop and mobile friendly pages for the same request. Regardless though, the attribute is in the request, so whichever object has access to the `request` object will also have access to the attribute.

Comment: you should identify if it is a mobile or note, and then forward the correct jps for the plattform

Answer (score 1):

You can forward to only **one JSP** using RequestDispatcher.forward(..).

You cannot dispatch multiple times using Forward because, doing RequestDispatcher.forward(..) will **commit and close and the response**.

What you can do is **propagate the request to a jsp** that uses a RequestDispatcher to **propagate the request to another jsp** and so on....

But all this is done **sequentialy** , **NOT simultaneously**.

This [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) will give you a better idea.

Comment: Hey, was wondering if the answer helped you for the question asked?

Answer (score 0):

You can not forward to two urls at a time. If you want in both pages then try to put your attribute to session.or from your redirected jsp you can check which page you want(mobile or normal).